# Best design pattern for managing asymmetrical resource use

Tags: java, design-patterns, try-with-resources

I wanted to canvas some opinions on the best design pattern for working with managed resources, where two distinct resources are involved but you need to release them in the opposite order to that which they were acquired.

First, let me set the scene. We are working with two types of objects Documents, and Collections of Documents. A Collection of Documents literally contains references to the Documents and some metadata per-document.

Originally we had a symmetrical pattern which flowed like:

1. Lock Collection
2. Do useful stuff with Collection
3. Lock Document
4. Do useful stuff with Collection and Document
5. Unlock Document
6. Unlock Collection

and in code was represented like:

```
Collection col = null;
try {
    col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK);

    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK);

        // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }

} finally {
    if (col != null) {
        col.close();
    }
}
```

Now that we have `try-with-resources` since Java 7, we have improved this so that Java code delineation automatically releases the resources:

```
try (final Collection col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

    try (final Document doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

        // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

    }

}
```

The problem we have is that keeping the Collection locked whilst we perform operations on the document is inefficient, as other threads have to wait, and often the operations on the document don't require modifying the Collection.

So we would like to move to an asymmetrical pattern which allows us to release the Collection as soon as possible. The flow should be like:

1. Lock Collection
2. Do useful stuff with Collection
3. Lock Document
4. Do anything that requires both Collection and Document (rare)
5. Unlock Collection
6. Do useful stuff with Document
7. Unlock Document

I am wondering about the best pattern for implementing this asymmetrical approach in code. This could obviously be done with try/finally etc like so:

```
Collection col = null;
Document doc = null;
try {
    col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK);

    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection
    try {
        doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK);

        // Here we do any operations that require both the Collection and Document (rare).

    } finally {
        if (col != null) {
        col.close();
    }

    // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

} finally {
    if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I can also think of a `try-with-resources` scheme where we exchange the resource release order but I am wondering if that makes reading the code less understandable. For example:

```
try (final ManagedRelease<Collection> mcol =
        new ManagedRelease<>(getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK))) {

    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

    try (final ManagedRelease<Document> mdoc =
            mcol.withAsymetrical(mcol.resource.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK))) {

        // Here we do any operations that require both the Collection and Document (rare).

    }  // NOTE: Collection is released here

    // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

}  // NOTE: Document is released here
```

The `ManagedRelease` class:

```
private static class ManagedRelease<T extends AutoCloseable> implements AutoCloseable {
    final T resource;
    private Supplier<Optional<Exception>> closer;

    public ManagedRelease(final T resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.closer = asCloserFn(resource);
    }

    private ManagedRelease(final T resource, final Supplier<Optional<Exception>> closer) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.closer = closer;
    }

    public <U extends AutoCloseable> ManagedRelease<U> withAsymetrical(final U otherResource) {
        // switch the closers of ManagedRelease<T> and ManagedRelease<U>
        final ManagedRelease<U> asymManagedResource = new ManagedRelease<>(otherResource, closer);
        this.closer = asCloserFn(otherResource);
        return asymManagedResource;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        final Optional<Exception> maybeEx = closer.get();
        if(maybeEx.isPresent()) {
            throw maybeEx.get();
        }
    }

    private static Supplier<Optional<Exception>> asCloserFn(final AutoCloseable autoCloseable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                autoCloseable.close();
                return Optional.empty();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                return Optional.of(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I would welcome opinions on whether the `try-with-resources` approach to asymmetrical resource management is a sensible one or not, and also any pointers to other patterns that might be more appropriate.

Comment: Your problem statement looks like thread Synchronization type. So, I will suggest to design this by using Semaphore.

Comment: @adamretter Forgive my ignorance but what libraries are you using such that there is a `close` method for a `Collection` class. Also what library does the `Document` class belong to? Is this information irrelevant to answering the question?

Comment: @Cking they are from eXist-db, however I don't think you need to worry at all about the detail of the Document or Collection class. Calling close on either just releases the associated resources (in this instance a lock).

Comment: @gul-md-ershad I think you would need to explain why and how using a semaphore would lead to a better design pattern.

Comment: Looks pretty much like lock upgrade/downgrade idiom. So you first acquire write (exclusive) lock on the Collection for writes, then downgrading to read (shared) lock once the Collection is only accessed for reads. Potentially switching from write to read and back can be done many times. However, it is only feasible in presence of proper locking support.

Comment: @yegodm I don't want to downgrade the Collection lock from Write to Read, rather I want to release it completely, but do so early.

Answer (score 4):

The first question seems to be under-specified expected behavior. Particularly, if `Collection.close` throws an `Exception`, what should happen? Should `Document` processing be continued? Should part of the processing of the Document done under both locks be rolled back?

If the answer is `Collection.close` never actually throws any exceptions (or you don't care what happens if it does), IMHO the simplest solution is to make your `Collection.close` idempotent and then explicitly call it in the middle of the `try-with-resources` block where it is appropriate. Also it makes a great sense to make "usual" `Collection` methods raise something like `IllegalStateException` if called on a closed `Collection`. Then you second example would become something like this:

```
try (final Collection col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {
    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

    try (final Document doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

        // Here we do any operations that require both the Collection and Document (rare).


        // NOTE: usually Collection is released here
        col.close();
        // optionally make `col` not final and explicitly set it to `null`
        // here so IDE would notify you about any usage after this point

        // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

    }  
}
```

If you can't change `Collection.close` code, you can change your `ReleaseManager` to make `close` idempotent. Optionally you might also rename it to something like `ResourceManager`. add a getter there and always access resource only via that getter. And the getter will throw `IllegalStateException` if called after `close`.

If `Collection.close` may actually throw some exception and you do care about such scenarios, it is hard to provide a solution without knowing what expected behavior is.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a common, complete and chaining solution like this:

```
   public static void sample() {
    Resource resourceA = new Resource("A");
    Resource resourceB = new Resource("B");
    LockVisitor.create(resourceA)
        .lock()// lock A
        .doOnValue(Main::doSomething)// do for A
        .with(resourceB)// join with B
        .lock()// lock A & B (A has been locked)
        .doOnBoth(Main::doSomething)// do for A and B
        .toRight()// only need B (unlock A)
        .doOnValue(Main::doSomething)// do for B
        .close();// unlock B
  }

  private static void doSomething(Resource... rs) {
    System.out.println("do with: " + Arrays.toString(rs));
  }
```

and `sample` will output what is you expected:

```
lock: Resource(A)
do with: [Resource(A)]
lock: Resource(B)
do with: [Resource(A), Resource(B)]
unlock: Resource(A)
do with: [Resource(B)]
unlock: Resource(B)
```

First, we should define the lockable resource. How to lock and how to unlock.

```
public interface Lockable extends AutoCloseable {

  void lock() throws Exception;

  void unlock() throws Exception;

  boolean isLocked();

  @Override
  default void close() throws Exception {
    unlock();
  }
}
```

You can let your class implement this interface for more clear call.

Then we can build our `LockVisitor` (for reduce the length of this answer, I delete method implemention. [You can find the complete code on github.](https://github.com/XDean/StackOverflow/tree/master/src/main/java/xdean/stackoverflow/java/Q46864834))

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

public class LockVisitor<T extends Lockable> implements AutoCloseable {
  public static <T extends Lockable> LockVisitor<T> create(T lockable) {
    return new LockVisitor<>(lockable);
  }

  T value;
  Exception error;

  public LockVisitor(T value);

  public LockVisitor<T> lock();

  public LockVisitor<T> unlock();

  public LockVisitor<T> doOnValue(Consumer<T> func);

  public LockVisitor<T> doOnError(Consumer<Exception> func);

  public <B extends Lockable> TwoLockVisitor<T, B> with(LockVisitor<B> other);

  public <B extends Lockable> TwoLockVisitor<T, B> with(B other);
}
```

and our `TwoLockVisitor` for visit two resources together:

```
import io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

public class TwoLockVisitor<A extends Lockable, B extends Lockable> {
  public static <A extends Lockable, B extends Lockable> TwoLockVisitor<A, B> create(A a, B b) {
    return new TwoLockVisitor<>(LockVisitor.create(a), LockVisitor.create(b));
  }

  LockVisitor<A> left;
  LockVisitor<B> right;

  public TwoLockVisitor(LockVisitor<A> left, LockVisitor<B> right);

  public TwoLockVisitor<A, B> lock();

  public TwoLockVisitor<A, B> unlock();

  public TwoLockVisitor<A, B> doOnLeft(Consumer<A> func);

  public TwoLockVisitor<A, B> doOnRight(Consumer<B> func);

  public TwoLockVisitor<A, B> doOnBoth(BiConsumer<A, B> func);

  public LockVisitor<A> toLeft();

  public LockVisitor<B> toRight();
}
```

Now, you can use the classes to managing your resource with any order.

Comment: I actually really like this pattern. I can see that with a few changes to the naming of methods I could have quite a neat approach. Unfortunately using Lambda's is a little difficult in this instance, as I have to integrate with existing code which is very exception heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ManagedRelease` scheme definitely does make the code less understandable. The most direct explicit writeup of your intentions using language features goes like this:

```
try (final Collection col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

    // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

}
try (final Collection col = getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK;
    final Document doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

    // Here we do any operations that require both the Collection and Document (rare).

}
try (final Document doc = col.getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

    // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

}
```

The problem with this is the extra release and re-acquisition of each lock, and also that `col` is out of scope for the last `getDocument` call so it won't quite compile as is.

I would suggest resolving this with a different take on the `ManagedRelease` concept, lifted up one level. The usage pattern I envision for this would work like this:

```
// The lambdas here are Supplier
try (final ReleaseManager<Collection> colManager = new ReleaseManager<>(() -> getCollection("col1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK);
    final ReleaseManager<Document> docManager = new ReleaseManager<>(() -> colManager.getResource().get().getDocument("doc1 name", LockMode.WRITE_LOCK)) {

    try (final Managed<Collection> colManaged = colManager.getResource()) {

        // Here we do any operations that only require the Collection

    } // Here the resource close does nothing

    try (final Managed<Collection> colManaged = colManager.getResourceForLastUse();
        final Managed<Document> docManaged = docManager.getResource()) {

        // Here we do any operations that require both the Collection and Document (rare).

    } // Here the close of colManaged actually closes it, while docManaged.close() is a no-op

    try (final Managed<Document> docManaged = docManager.getResourceForLastUse()) {

        // Here we do some operations on the document (of the Collection)

    } // Here the document gets closed
} // Here the managers get closed, which would close their resources if needed
```

This has the same clarity of which resources are used in each block, uses the try-with-resources language feature, releases each resource immediately after its last use, and only acquires each lock once.

For the specification of `ReleaseManager`:

`ReleaseManager` here is a generic class that takes a `Supplier` for a resource, invokes it lazily on the first `getResource()` call, and memoizes the result for future calls. `getResource()` returns a wrapper that does nothing when closed, `getResourceForLastUse()` returns a wrapper that actually does close the resource when the wrapper is closed; I wrote these as being the same class, but you could make them different classes instead, I'm not sure if it really makes anything clearer.

`ReleaseManager` itself also implements `AutoCloseable`, and its `close()` implementation is a failsafe that closes the resource if it has been gotten but not closed. I would consider having it also log a warning in some manner, to draw attention in case a resource's last use is not properly declared to be its last. And for one final consideration, both resource retrieval methods should throw if the resource has already been closed.

I'm leaving the implementation of `ReleaseManager` as an exercise for you if you like this solution.

Comment: This doesn't look to me as a good solution. Particularly, the whole point of having a lock is that we have a continuous execution of the piece of code that might break some invariants in between but fixes them all at the end. So the main issue with this solution is not performance for double acquiring-releasing. It is the fact that some other thread can acquire lock for Collection between two acquisition be your thread and it might see inconsistent state.

Comment: @SergGr That's a problem with the initial "this expresses your intent" block, not for my actual solution. No other thread can acquire lock between two acquisitions because there's only one acquisition. `ReleaseManager` acquires the lock the first time the resource is called for, and doesn't release it until the last use of the resource is done.

Comment: I don't like this design because it is hard to guess from this code without digging into the implementation details that `getResourceForLastUse` is such a special function. Moreover, if the logic that requires both locks is conditional, the code that releases the `Collection` lock early would look very strange (or will rely on the order of `if` and `try-with-resource` which is also ugly). And correct working of your `docManager` in this scenario is also  highly implementation-dependent. Also it is absolutely not clear why `colManager.getResource()` call is wrapped into a`try-with-resource`.

Comment: I mean that your `getResource` is called 3 times in the code and only one of three calls is wrapped in the try-with-resource. Why? Why it returns `Managed` at all if that `Managed` does nothing in its `close`? Given such signatures I don't think that it is easy to guess that `getResource` does nothing in `close` but `getResourceForLastUse` actually closes. And this is exactly the mistake I made leaving my first comment. P.S. _This is an answer to a comment that seems to be already removed but I left mine as it clarifies my concenrs_

Comment: @SergGr Technically all three of those calls are wrapped in try-with-resource, though one is further wrapped in a lambda. The reason `getResource` returns `Managed` is so that it can fit into the try-with-resource pattern without breaking the desired behavior, which seems to me to make for better readability. The fact that the actual resource is wrapped at all should imply that its closure is not necessarily tied to the closure of the wrapper.

Comment: sorry I just don't get how `getResource` in `-> colManager.getResource().get().` is wrapped into the try-with-resource. It seems impossible since is not stored anywhere and immediately disposed just after the `get` call. And this is the place I pointed to as "_highly implementation-dependent_" in case of conditional logic.  Also I still don't get what the benefits of putting the result of `getResource` into the try-with-resource are. AFAIU the only thing `try-with-resource` do is ensuring that `close` will be called but this makes no sense as `close` in this case does nothing anyway.

Comment: @SergGr It's a lambda. `colManager.getResource().get()` is not actually executed on that line, it is the body of the implementation of a `Supplier` object's `get()` method. The `Supplier` object is passed to `docManager`'s constructor, which stores it to be invoked later when `docManager.getResource()` is called - in a try-with-resource.

Comment: @SergGr Putting the result of `getResource()` in a try-with-resource strictly speaking has no operational effect. You are completely correct on that point. It does, however, communicate semantic meaning to a programmer reading the code - "I'm getting this resource and doing something with it in this limited block of code" - and confines the scope of the variable it's stored in to that block.

Comment: Hey @Douglas this is a very interesting approach, and I do really like how it works technically. I think the main confusion of this comes from the naming of `getResource` and `getResourceForLastUse` as evidenced by your discussion with @SergGr; which could make it difficult for the user to understand the scope of the locking. I do think it has some charm though, and is not an approach I would have thought of. Thanks for your suggestion it has certainly given me food-for-thought :-)